# Not able to import pandas in R

Tags: python, r, pandas

I am calling a python script from R/shiny as:

```
system("python /Users/Downloads/Untitled3.py EMEA regulatory '10% productivity saves SOW'")
```

It is not able to import pandas.

But when I straight call the script from the terminal as:

```
python /Users/Downloads/Untitled3.py EMEA regulatory '10% productivity saves SOW'
```

It is able to import pandas. I guess some version issue in python.I have anaconda installed. Can anyone of you please help me in rectifying the issue.

Although not required as, script starts as:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import sys

from difflib import SequenceMatcher
##### More code#########
```

Comment: In terminal enter `python` and check version. You may need to run `python3`.

Comment: It is python 2.7. So you are saying that I have to install python 3. No other fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem**

You have the default system `python` and then the `anaconda` distribution as well.

Merely running the command that you are running from `R` calls the default system `python` that doesn't have the required packages.

**Fix**

Assuming you have anaconda installed at `/Users/<username>/anaconda/bin/python` (that's the default mac installation folder),

the `R` command that you should run is -

```
system("/Users/<username>/anaconda/bin/python /Users/Downloads/Untitled3.py EMEA regulatory '10% productivity saves SOW'")
```

This ensures that you are explicitly using `anaconda`'s python binaries which will pick up on the `pandas` and other relevant libraries installed there.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Vivek. Very articulate response. Have accepted your answer.:)