# Access the output of python script in R executed through system command

Tags: python, r, system

My current question is follow up question to the link below.

[Not able to import pandas in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50316235/not-able-to-import-pandas-in-r)

I have executed the python code in R with system command. Now at the end of python script I want to access the Dataframe created in R. One way is to save the Dataframe created in python with df.to_csv and then import it in R. But I am wondering any efficient way to directly access the output in R.

```
x=system("/Users/ravinderbhatia/anaconda/bin/python /Users/ravinderbhatia/Downloads/Untitled3.py EMEA regulatory '10% productivity saves SOW'")
```

output dataframe is:

```
description                       status region
10  10% productivity saves SOW   pending   EMEA
16  10% productivity saves SOW  approved   EMEA
```

X just contains 0/1(status). As mentioned above, how to access Dataframe directly in R without saving it.

```
Python script used is:


import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import sys


from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

arg1 = sys.argv[1]
arg2 = sys.argv[2]
arg3 = sys.argv[3]
print (arg1)
print (arg2)
print (arg3)

def get_similar_CRs(arg1, arg2,arg3):
##create dummy data
    cr_id=range(1,41)

    description=['change in design','More robust system required',
                 'Grant system adminstrator rights',
                 'grant access to all products',
                 'Increase the credit limit',
                 'EDAP Scenario',
                 'Volume prpductivity for NA 2015',
                 '5% productivity saves SOW',
                 'effort reduction',
                 'reduction of false claims',
                 'Volume productivity EMEA',
                 'Volume productivity for NA 2016',
                 '10% productivity saves SOW',
                ]
    region=['EMEA','Asia Pacific','UK']

    business=['card','secured loan','mortgage']
    type=['regulatory','system','audit']

    status=['pending','approved']

    data=pd.DataFrame()
    data['description']=np.random.choice(description, 40)
    data['cr_id']=cr_id
    data['region']=np.random.choice(region,40)
    data['business']=np.random.choice(business, 40)
    data['status']=np.random.choice(status,40)
    data['type']=np.random.choice(type,40)

    subset_data=data.loc[data.region == arg1]
    print (subset_data.head())
    subset_data=subset_data.loc[subset_data.type ==arg2]

    ##This has to be captured dynamically
    new_cr=arg3

    cr_list=data['description'].unique().tolist()

    similar_CR=[] ###global variable
#     for new_cr in new_cr_lis
    for cr in cr_list:
        result=similar(new_cr,cr)
        if result >=0.8:
            similar_CR.append(cr)

    temp=subset_data.loc[subset_data.description.isin(similar_CR)]
    temp=temp[['description','status','region']]
    return temp

temp= get_similar_CRs (arg1, arg2, arg3)

print temp
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into the `reticulate` package (see the [online vignette](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/calling_python.html)).

You can run your file with `py_run_file()` and access the python main module with`py`. So lets say your file is called "Untitled3.py" and the data frame it creates is called `df`, then

```
library(reticulate)

use_python("/Users/ravinderbhatia/anaconda/bin/python")

py_run_file("Untitled3.py")

py$df
```

---

**Edit**

Alternatively, you can import only the function from the python file and just call them from inside R. E.g., have the python file as

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import sys
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

def get_similar_CRs(arg1, arg2,arg3):
    ##create dummy data
    cr_id=range(1,41)

    description=['change in design','More robust system required',
                 'Grant system adminstrator rights',
                 'grant access to all products',
                 'Increase the credit limit',
                 'EDAP Scenario',
                 'Volume prpductivity for NA 2015',
                 '5% productivity saves SOW',
                 'effort reduction',
                 'reduction of false claims',
                 'Volume productivity EMEA',
                 'Volume productivity for NA 2016',
                 '10% productivity saves SOW',
                ]
    region=['EMEA','Asia Pacific','UK']

    business=['card','secured loan','mortgage']
    type=['regulatory','system','audit']

    status=['pending','approved']

    data=pd.DataFrame()
    data['description']=np.random.choice(description, 40)
    data['cr_id']=cr_id
    data['region']=np.random.choice(region,40)
    data['business']=np.random.choice(business, 40)
    data['status']=np.random.choice(status,40)
    data['type']=np.random.choice(type,40)

    subset_data=data.loc[data.region == arg1]
    print (subset_data.head())
    subset_data=subset_data.loc[subset_data.type ==arg2]

    ##This has to be captured dynamically
    new_cr=arg3

    cr_list=data['description'].unique().tolist()

    similar_CR=[] ###global variable
#     for new_cr in new_cr_lis
    for cr in cr_list:
        result=similar(new_cr,cr)
        if result >=0.8:
            similar_CR.append(cr)

    temp=subset_data.loc[subset_data.description.isin(similar_CR)]
    temp=temp[['description','status','region']]
    return temp
```

and then run

```
library(reticulate)

# To install pandas and numpy in the regular python environment
py_install("pandas", "numpy")

py_run_file("Untitled3.py")

py$get_similar_CRs("EMEA", "regulatory", "10% productivity saves SOW")

#>                   description  status region
#> 2  10% productivity saves SOW pending   EMEA
#> 25 10% productivity saves SOW pending   EMEA
```

Comment: I have heard about reticulate package. So you are suggesting to avoid system command and better use reticulate package.

Comment: Yes. It will provide you with a much easier to use interface with your python code; you can also create python functions and call them from R.

Comment: py_run_file is giving me the same issue which I faced in previous question. Pandas not found. It is executing system python, not Anaconda Python.

Comment: You can specify which python to use with `use_python()`. See updated answer.

Comment: It is difficult to help further without a minimal reproducible example. Can you share your python code?

Comment: Added to the question.

Comment: yes just saw that. it should be OK. The last command I can do df=py$get_similar_CRs(arg1, arg2) and then do further processing.

Comment: still I am getting no module named pandas. It should not occur now. Cannot understand.

Comment: Try `use_python("/Users/ravinderbhatia/anaconda/bin/python", require = TRUE)`.