# Python is not able to find libraries while accessing from shiny script

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, shiny, shiny-server

I have a python script which is working fine while I'm running it from terminal. The same script I'm trying to invoke from shiny application with the arguments, but the shiny-server log says    `File "/home/linuxadmin/Desktop/ADLS_test2.py", line 9, in <module> from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.identity'` But `pip list` is displaying `azure-common 1.1.28  azure-core 1.29.5    azure-identity 1.15.0    azure-keyvault-secrets 4.7.0    azure-storage-blob 12.19.0`

I could understand that python is not able to recognize the libraries while the script is invoking from shiny server app. Below is the sample script from shiny-server app I'm trying to invoke python file. How do I set up the python libraries path to look for, in the Python file?

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

observeEvent(input$submitid,{
 source <- renderText({ input$caption })
 destination <- renderText({ input$caption2 })
 system('python3 /home/linuxadmin/Desktop/ADLS_test2.py source destination')
 output$info <- paste0('Source : ', source, ' | Destination : ', destination)
})

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, thanks to this question [Access the output of python script in R executed through system command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50319127/access-the-output-of-python-script-in-r-executed-through-system-command) which gave me clue about how to mention the python path in `system` command. First I had to get the python installed path from the machine and instead of just `system('python3 /home/linuxadmin/Desktop/ADLS_test2.py source destination')` , I had to give this way. `system('/usr/bin/python3 /home/linuxadmin/Desktop/ADLS_test2.py source destination')`. This way the python is able to import the libraries when invoked from shiny app.